# Strange tag being generated in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, abbr

I have the following `GetText()` function, which relates to my question, which is being called in the following place:

```
myGridView.DataSource = stuff.Select(s => new
{
   //...some stuff here
   f.Text = GetText();
}
myGridView.DataBind();
```

GetText looks like the following:

```
private void string GetText()
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append("<abbr title=\"Testing\">");
    sp.Append("This is the Text that I want to display");
sb.Append("<\abbr>");
}
```

So essentially, all I want to do is be able to have the following HTML on my webpage:

```
<abbr title="Testing">This is the text that I want to display</abbr>
```

However, there is a mysterious  tag that shows up. In google chrome, I looked at th the console and I saw that it looked like this:

```
<abbr title="Testing">This is the text that I want to display<bbr></abbr>
```

There is an extraneous  tag that is generated when I add in the line `sb.Append("<\abbr>");`
This is fixed when I remove that line, but I would like to find a better solution since this makes the code look awkward.

I also tried doing the following instead of the multi-lined `sb.Appends()` but the extra  text is still shown.

```
sb.Append(string.Format("<abbr title=\"testing\">{0}<\abbr>",Text));
```

NOTE: Assume that Text is a string which equals the text that I want to display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how your method shoul like

```
    private string GetText()
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append("<abbr title=\"Testing\">");
        sb.Append("This is the Text that I want to display");
        sb.Append("</abbr>");

        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

"\" is an escape character :)

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
sb.Append("</abbr>");
```

probably the `\abbr` is interpreted as an escape char `\a` followed by the `bbr>` text

By the way, looking [at the escape sequences on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21280bw.aspx) it seems that `\a` is the escape sequence for  the BELL character. (No, I don't think that you should hear a beep from your PC)

Answer (score 2):

Your end tag is wrong. It should be `</abbr>` not `<\abbr>`.

`<\abbr>` will include an escaped `a` (which means nothing), inside the `<bbr>`. Chrome apparently closes the `<abbr>` tag. So the superfluous tag is actually `</abbr>` not `<bbr>`.

Answer (score 1):

Just a guess but is it because you have a backslash instead of slash in your closing tag?

```
sb.Append("<\abbr>");
```

vs

```
sb.Append("</abbr>");
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, this is the issue:

```
sb.Append("<\abbr>");
```

... but it's worth looking at *exactly* what's happening.

That's appending `<`, then a U+0007 (the "alert" character, or bell), then `bbr>`. If you'd done this with a character which *wasn't* a valid escape character (e.g. `"<\zfoo>"`) then you'd have received a compile-time error. In some other cases you might have been able to see it in the HTML. It's only because you picked a completely invisible control character that it was harder to see.

As an aside, I don't think I've *ever* seen a C# program which needed `\a`. I wish it wasn't a valid escape character - along with the `\x` hex sequence...